# If i reload my react page it returns a blank webpage

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am developing an app using react-redux and when i am not logged in, I get a blank page and if i check in the console, i get "Cannot read properties of null (reading: users")

I think the problem is from my user reducer.

here's my reducer code

```
export const userReducer = (
  state = localStorage.getItem('app_user')
    ? {
        firstName: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('app_user')).user.firstName,
        lastName: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('app_user')).user.lastName,
        email: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('app_user')).user.email,
        storeName: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('app_user')).user.storeName,
        role: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('app_user')).user.role,
        profilePicUrl: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('app_user')).user
          .profilePicUrl,
        _id: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('app_user')).user._id,
        token: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('app_user')).token,
      }
    : null,
  action
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOGGED_IN_USER':
      return action.payload
    case 'LOGOUT':
      return action.payload
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

what i have tried to achieve from the code is to always check my user storage and see if the user data is available there. If it isn't it should otherwise return null.

How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: You are checking the `app_user` storage exists, but not checking it has a non-null `user` property. Without knowing the data structure it's tough to tell you exactly what checks you'll need, but at the very least, a `!== null` on `.user` seems necessary.

Comment: Can you update your question with your console log error? we can identify the exact error then

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting this error is because users property is not readable while rendering the component, your data do not exist on page load and after reducer finishes it sets the data so you have to put check for users.

If users is **array** you should put a check for its **length**, or check for null **users !== null** depending on data type of users.

You could also try

```html
!!users ? <div>render something</div> : null
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from checking if app_user exists, you also need to check that it contains "user" as a non-empty object. I would do this.

```js
state = localStorage.getItem('app_user') && Boolean(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('app_user')).user && Object.keys(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('app_user')).user).length>0)
?{
        firstName: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('app_user')).user.firstName,
        lastName: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('app_user')).user.lastName,
        email: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('app_user')).user.email,
        storeName: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('app_user')).user.storeName,
        role: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('app_user')).user.role,
        profilePicUrl: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('app_user')).user
          .profilePicUrl,
        _id: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('app_user')).user._id,
        token: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('app_user')).token,
      }
    : null,
```